# Zend: Creating models for a products table

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm trying to create two models, `products` and `product_manufacturers` so that I can pull in manufacturers as well as products, edit them in the admin if necessary, and the usual CRUD stuff. Here's the schema for the tables ( it's not *finalized* so if you have any suggestions go ahead ).

```
CREATE TABLE `product_manufacturers` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `manufacturer_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Example data:

( products ) -

```
id product_name manufacturer_id
1  iPod Nano 4g 1
```

( product_manufacturers ) -

```
id manufacturer_name active
1  Apple             1
```

I've created two models, but I'm having trouble pulling in the products based on the active product manufacturers ( and yes, I'm using a model autoloader ).

```
protected function _initAutoload ()
{
    // Add autoloader empty namespace
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
    array(
    'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH ,
    'namespace' => '' ,
    'resourceTypes' => array(
        'form' => array('path' => 'forms/' ,
        'namespace' => 'Form_') ,
        'model' => array('path' => 'models/' ,
        'namespace' => 'Model_')
    )
    ));
    // Return it so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
    return $autoLoader;
}
```

application/models/Product.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php';

class Model_Product extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /**
     * The default table name 
     */
    protected $_name = 'products';
    protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_Manufacturer');
}
```

application/models/Manufacturer.php:

```
class Model_Manufacturer extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /**
     * The default table name 
     */
    protected $_name = 'product_manufacturers';
    protected $_referenceMap = array(
 'Model_Product' => array(
     'manufacturer_id' => array('id'),
     'id' => array('manufacturer_id'),
 ),
    );
}
```

I have a feeling I'm completely doing things wrong, as I'm creating an object from the Products Model and trying to print out all products which have a corresponding manufacturer, and that manufacturer is active.

```
 $model = new Model_Product();
 $results = $model->fetchAll();
 foreach ($results as $result) {
     //print_r($result);
     echo $result->product_name;
 }
```

I'm new to model creation, could anyone provide advice on how I could properly change my current code so that the products model properly relies on the manufacturers model?

I have a feeling that I'm improperly setting the dependentTables/referenceMap, and instead of using the generic `fetchAll` method I should be creating a custom method in either of the models to do the fetching and maybe a manual join with the manufacturers table, or would a proper referenceMap and dependentTables property solve that issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few things to fix up here, but here are a few tips.

i. Table models work a little better if their names are pluralized.  They sound better in the magic methods (e.g. $product_set = findProducts() instead of findModel_Product())

ii. The reference map is the important one and allows for those nifty magic selection methods (e.g. findParentX()) to work.  It belongs in the *dependent* table, which is the `product` table here because it references the `product_manufacturer`.

```
  // in Model_Product
  protected $_referenceMap = array(

    // rule name
    'Manufacturer' => array(

      'columns'       => 'manufacturer_id',     // this column
      'refTableClass' => 'Model_Manufacturer',  // references that table object
      'refColumns'    => 'id'                   // and references that column
    )
  );
```

iii. Move dependent tables entry to your `product_manufacturers` table model, if you'd like: it's used only to replicate `ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE` database commands, though.  (Leave it for now)

```
// in manufacturer table model
protected $_dependentTables = array('Model_Product');
```

**Fetching**

To get a product's manufacturer, do this:

```
$manufacturer = $product_row->findParentManufacturer();
```

To get a manufacturer's products, do this:

```
$product_set = $manufacturer_row->findProducts(); // Well, findModel_Product(), which is why you should rename your table ;)
```

For other magic methods originating from each single row, dig into the source code for `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` (especially `public function __call`).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. "it's really only useful if you want to cascade deleted and updates through PHP" - so are you saying it's better to just keep it more simple by creating a DB Select object, which I've been doing up to this point if I don't need cascading and such?

Comment: regarding the active manufacturers, I know the way to do it with the select object is just, `->where('product_manufacturers.active=?',1`.. so you're saying because I'm doing it a different way it's going to be harder than this?

Comment: Regarding your first comment, I've clarified my post -- the $_dependantTables is used to replicate ON DELETE/UPDATE CASCADE database operations, if you don't have foreign keys in your database.  Maybe leave it for now.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, I have edited the very last part of my post.  What I was *really* saying was simply, dig into the Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract's __call function code to learn more about the magic methods (including limiting the results using a 'select' object).  Your use of 'select' is good, I think.

Answer (score 0):

i have implemented reference maps and i'm retrieving the parent's details of a record using the $childObject->findParentObject() method- which works well for single instances of a child object.

however i have an issue with using this to retrieve the details of parent objects for multiple child rows [for display purposes] though, which currently involves doing a select to retrieve the initial record set then traversing this, using the findParentObject() method to get what i want for that record.  thus i've decided to ignore the reference map and do a join for this, bypassing the reference map completely.  this works fine, is one select only and is quicker.

my question then is is there a nice way of using the reference map to achieve the same results, using one query?  the way i'm currently using the reference map feels a bit contrived, although it feels like for the sake of purity i should be using it to do what i need...

rob ganly